# Updating legacy C code headers to C++ stdlib

Tags: c++

Inherited a slew of legacy C code, and am in the process of porting it to compile on Linux with GCC (g++). Since we are going to be using C++ in the future and I'm fixing the "custom" library header files anyways (and compiler warnings), is it safe to update the old C headers to use the newer C++ style ones.

So things like

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Instead of

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

To my knowledge the only difference between the two is that cstdlib has things in the `std::` namespace.

Would anything make this a bad idea?

Comment: Why try to shoe-horn it into C++?  It would probably be easier to compile it as C, and then link to it as C from newly developed C++ code.  There is no advantage in converting it to C++.

Comment: Other than it will stop your code compiling as C should you still need to, probably not. I'd write new code using them, but I'm not sure that going changing it is the best use of your time perhaps?

Comment: @William: There are plenty of advantages to compiling as C++.  For one, maintenance programmers can begin to use C++ features here and there.  For another, you don't have to mess with `extern "C"` declarations to use the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code may change in very subtle ways, due to the fact that the C++ standard headers use overloading where C used different names.  This is most likely to cause trouble with `cmath`.

`stdlib.h` isn't going anywhere, so feel free to keep using it.

For example, compare:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    double x = -2;
    cout << (3/abs(x)) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The results [before](http://ideone.com/ECd3s) and [after](http://ideone.com/p2Wv6) switching to C++ headers are very different, even though the exact same C++ compiler and options are used in both cases.

Comment: Great use case. Looks like I'll leave things as is, and update on an as needed basis.

Answer (score 1):

They're exactly the same (on most systems) except for the namespace thing.